# Modulus behavior in Q

Tags: kdb

Why is it that

```
    -4.5 mod 2.3
0.1
```

Going by the definition in Q4Mortals:

> For a positive divisor, the remainder is defined as the difference
>   between the dividend and the largest integral multiple of the divisor
>   not exceeding the absolute value of the dividend.

2.3 is the lagest integral multiple not exceeding abs -4.5. Taking the difference, -4.5 - 2.3 = -6.8

If this definition is wrong (which it seems to be), then what is the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

think it should be just

> For a positive divisor, the remainder is defined as the difference
>   between the dividend and the largest integral multiple of the divisor
>   not exceeding the dividend.

Comment: How so? I am suggesting based on function behavior what the definition should be. How does it warrant to be put into clarification?

Comment: @SanketKachhela: I think we agree that the book definition is wrong. We are now trying to reverse engineer the correct definition given behavior of the function.